# How to hide input field in TextFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am customizing flutter ecommerce mobile app from codecanyon.
I want to hide the Pincode box. There are two ways to get the value in the Pincode box either manually or from google mab.
I want the value to be selected only from google mab.
how can I hide the text box?

```dart
setPincode() {
  return TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    controller: pincodeC,
    style: Theme.of(context)
        .textTheme
        .subtitle2
        .copyWith(color: colors.fontColor),
    inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
    onSaved: (String value) {
      pincode = value;

    },
    validator: (val) => validatePincode(
      val,
      getTranslated(context, 'PIN_REQUIRED'),
    ),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: getTranslated(context, 'PINCODEHINT_LBL'),
      isDense: true,
    ),
  );
}
```

[image: The app page]

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with the visibility widget, it gets a bool value that indicates if the child can be visible or not, i believe this widget solves your problem.

exemple:

```
return Visibility(
                  visible: controller.cards.isNotEmpty,
                  replacement: const Text(
                    "Ops! Você ainda não tem eventos para esta data",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: I tried to use visibility but how can I use child with return?

Comment: at what point should your widget be invisible? Knowing this, just create an observable variable that receives a default value of false for example, and when the action that you want your widget to disappear occurs, assign the value true to this variable. If you want advice, edit your question to make it easier for you to understand. Bad visibility logic basically is this. I edited my answer to make it clearer for you, see when my widget disappears I show a text as replacement, you can do the same with your widget